# Akaike‘s Information Criterion as a significance test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, information-theory

I stumbled upon a question related to AIC, where two nested models are given (no other information), and the difference between the number of parameters, $d$. The question states that the AIC can be interpreted as a significance test (my question is - why?), and that with a given difference in the number of parameters of the two models, the significance level can be calculated.

I am very confused by this and I don‘t really know where to start. I am also very new to this topic and I might be missing some obvious information to solve this problem, but any help and clarification is helpful!

Edit: I suppose that I could say that model 1 for example, has $k$ parameters, and that the model 2 has $k+d$ parameters. But I am still not able to deduce anything from this question.

Comment: Could you link the question?

Comment: Hi, it‘s from an exercise sheet in another language. It is the translated problem that I posted in this question.

Comment: I think you should check out F-tests for nested models, this is probably the direction your problem is going in. Compare the information needed to compute the F-statistic and the calculation to the information and calculation needed for AIC.

Answer (score 1):

The AIC is not a significance test, however it holds all the information to run a loglikelihood ratio test. The statistic of this is twice the difference between the loglikelihoods. This is under some conditions asymptotically distributed $\chi^2_r$ with $r$ being the difference between the dimensions, i.e., number of parameters. So you can reject the simpler model if this statistic is larger than a high $\chi^2_r$-quantile. Note that the expected value of $\chi^2_r$ is $r$. The difference between AIC values is just that test statistic minus twice the difference between the number of parameters; in other words, it adjusts the loglikelihood ratio difference by twice the expected difference under the $H_0$ (simpler model). Choosing the more complex model if it's better according to AIC would amount to testing with using $2r$ as critical value. This would correspond to a test level that varies with $r$ (about 0.1 for $r=3$ if I'm not mistaken, lower for larger $r$).